# What is being passed into this 'function(x)'?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm having a hard time grasping some finer details of javascript, I have this function `function(x)` it doesn't seem to be receiving any parameters. Maybe I'm not understanding the Math.sin part. I'm not sure. Any ideas on what is happening?

```
function makeDerivative( f, deltaX )
     {
        var deriv = function(x) // x isn't designated anywhere
        { 
           return ( f(x + deltaX) - f(x) )/ deltaX;
        }
        return deriv;
    }
    var cos = makeDerivative( Math.sin, 0.000001);
    // cos(0)     ~> 1
    // cos(pi/2)  ~> 0
```

**Update**
I tried this instead and got NaN, then 15

```
function addthings(x, y)
    {
                var addition = function(m)
          {
                return( x + y + m);
          }
          return addition;
    }

    var add = addthings(5, 5);
    alert(add());
    alert(add(5));
```

Comment: If you have control over the implementation, you should use the central difference quotient `( f(x + deltaX) - f(x - deltaX) ) / (2*deltaX)` as it has error O(deltaX²) opposed to O(deltaX) for the one-sided quotient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand how that code works you have to read more about [currying in functional javascript](http://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/) and [functions closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11394234)

Comment: @Reeno That may be true that links tend to die, this was from mozilla, and was the greatest help. It was the closure piece and how the environment and local variables stay alive.

Answer (score 2):

The outer function returns the inner function, so everything you pass to 
`cos` later theoretically is what you pass into the inner function. Imagine calling it like this:

```
console.log(makeDerivative( Math.sin, 0.000001)(0)); // 1
```

would output the same as if you're doing it as described

```
console.log(cos(0)) // 1
```

as `cos` is assigned reference to a function (the one that gets returned by `makeDerivative`).

Answer (score 2):

The other answers touch on the issue, but I'm going to try to get to the core of it.

JavaScript variables are untyped, which means that they can dynamically change what kind of variable they are.  On a simple level, this means that var `a` can be instantiated as an array, and then later assigned as a string on the fly.

But you can also store *entire functions* within those untyped variables.  For example;

```
var test = 'hey'
console.log(test)      //:: hey
test = function(input){ console.log('inner function: ' + input) }
console.log(test) //:: function(input){ console.log('inner function' + input) }
test() //:: inner function
test('with input') //:: inner function with input
```

Where //:: _____ represents the output to the console.

So the function you are using returns another dynamic function.  You can then call **that** function in a normal fashion, inputting the value for `x` when you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't really call the function in the code you posted.

The `makeDerivative` gets reference to Math.sin function and inside it uses it to create reference to function which  compute derivation of the passed function (see the `f` parameter).

In your example this reference is assigned to `cos` variable. If you called it with (`0`) argument, you would get `1` as return value and the argument (`0`) would be passed into that deriv function...

Comment: x isn't anywhere. before returning `deriv` what is being passed into x so that `f(x+deltaX)` does something? It can't be `f(undefined+deltaX) - f(undefined)/deltaX`

Comment: @christopherclark : `x` is parameter to function which is returned as reference. This function is actually called later, for example from the line which you commented out (`cos(0)` - `0` will be `x`).

Comment: @christopher clark x is the same as the variables f and deltaX. They are all parameters.

Comment: @WaffleStealer654 This doesn't seem to be the case. See my update

Comment: @christopherclark : In your edit, `add(5)` returns `5 + 5 + 5` which is 15. And `add()` is `5 + 5 + undefined` which is NaN. Anything plus undefined is `NaN` (not a number). What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: @WaffleStealer654 But according to you, `x is the same as the variables f and deltaX`. So wouldnt this work without m? what is m? what makes m get passed into `function(m)`? and why doesn't `function(m)` need `function(m,y,x)`?